# ElasticSearch polling is not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am creating a river as follows and when I create the records get indexed correctly. But it is not polling, that is, if I add a new record it is not reflected in the index.

```
{
"type" : "jdbc",
"jdbc" : {
    "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
    "user" : "[user]",
    "password" : "[password]",
    "sql" : "select PersonID as _id, LastName, FirstName, City from test.persons",       
    "strategy" : "simple",
    "poll" : "6s",
    "index" : "global",
    "type" : "persons",
    "bulk_size" : 100,
    "autocommit": true
}
}
```

What could be the wrong in the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poll parameter has been deprecated in recent versions of the JDBC River for Elasticsearch:

> **Obsolete parameters**
>
> In older versions of JDBC river, the following parameters were
>   available. They are no longer supported.
>
> driver - Class name of JDBC river. Since JDBC plugin requires JDBC
>   Version 4 (or higher), which is part of Java 6, this parameter is not
>   used any more.
>
> poll - interval for waiting between river invocations. Replaced by
>   schedule
>
> bulk_size - renamed to maxbulkactions
>
> max_bulk_requests - renamed to maxconcurrrentbulkactions
>
> bulk_flush_interval - no longer supported, replaced by internal flush
>   invocations

https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc

If you are not using a more recent version of the jdbc river I'd upgrade and then go thru the detailed documentation on the above page.

Comment: Yes, thanks later only noticed. I tried schedule and it works.